# Google calendar API not working in signed apk

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I integrate Google Calendar api properly and also works fine in unsigned apk.
But while i signed my app and try to access google calendar at that time api return below error.

```
Error com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
                                              {
                                                "code" : 403,
                                                "errors" : [ {
                                                  "domain" : "usageLimits",
                                                  "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
                                                  "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
                                                  "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
                                                } ],
                                                "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
                                              }
```

I also enabled Google Calendar api, CalDAV api.

So, I face this only in signed apk. unsigned is work perfect.

So, any one have idea that how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Basically u need to generate json file using SHA key with the signed key not debug key

Comment: @Madhur i am doing that